# Boolean expression to NOR-gates

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I'm having some trouble understanding how I can convert a boolean expression to a NOR-gate only expression. What I'm working with looks like this:

$$T = BD + \overline{A}B\overline{C} + \overline{A}CD$$

I know you're supposed to use deMorgan's theorem, but I'm not sure how to use it. Can I just select parts of the expression I want to use the theorem on, or does this change the result of the expression?

It would also be nice to see a step-by-step solution for the expression above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So Complement Law says \$\overline{\overline{X}} = X\$

We start with AND - OR.
$$BD + \overline{A}B\overline{C} + \overline{A}CD$$
Double Complement.
$$\overline{\overline{BD + \overline{A}B\overline{C} + \overline{A}CD}}$$
Use DeMorgan's Theorem to remove lower complement.
$$\overline{\overline{BD} • \overline{\overline{A}B\overline{C}} • \overline{\overline{A}CD}}$$
AND - OR has become NAND - NAND.  Use DeMorgan's on terms.
$$\overline{(\overline{B} + \overline{D}) • (A + \overline {B} + C) • (A + \overline{C} + \overline{D})}$$
NAND - NAND has become OR - NAND.  Use DeMorgan's Theorem to remove complement.
$$\overline{(\overline{B} + \overline{D})} + \overline{(A + \overline {B} + C)} + \overline{(A + \overline{C} + \overline{D})}$$
OR - NAND has become NOR - OR.  Double Complement again.
$$\overline{\overline{\overline{(\overline{B} + \overline{D})} + \overline{(A + \overline {B} + C)} + \overline{(A + \overline{C} + \overline{D})}}}$$
NOR - OR become NOR - NOR.  With an extra NOR connected as a NOT gate.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very logically set up. This will help me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way would be just to replace each operation with it's implementation with NOR gates:
$$NOT(A)=\bar{A} = \overline{(A+A)} = NOR(A,A)$$
$$OR(A,B) = A+B=\overline{\overline{A+B}}=NOT(NOR(A,B))$$
$$AND(A,B) = AB = \overline{\overline{AB}}=\overline{\bar{A}+\bar{B}}=NOR(NOT(A), NOT(B))$$ 
From here you can just substitute the operations.