# Two input nand gates and inverters to sum three products

Tags: digital-logic

I am trying to draw the logic gate of the following function using only two input nand gates and inverters A'C'D+AC'D'+AB'. So far I am stuck on trying create the AC'D' part. What I have drawn below would give me the some I think and not the product I am looking for.
[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/172663/boolean-expression-to-nor-gates/). The idea is the very same.

Comment: I think the problem is I am getting confused with the boolean algebra. Thanks @EugeneSh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify \$A'C'D+AC'D'+AB' ==> C'(A \oplus D)+AB' \$

You can draw \$(A \oplus D)\$using two-input NAND gates.

Let \$(A\oplus D)\$ = \$ X\$,

i.e, the equation becomes:
$$C'X+AB' $$

Using De-Morgan's theorem, we can tweek the equation into:

$$\overline{\overline{(C'X)}.\overline{AB'}}$$

Now you can directly draw the circuit using NAND and NOT gates.