# Realize using NOR gates only?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I came across a question regarding logic gates and I can't understand how to solve it.

Q) Construct the truth table and write the boolean output equation.

i) Realize using NOR gates only:
  $$f(A,B,C,D) = \prod (0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10) + \Phi(12, 13)$$

I tried to get Boolean equation using KMAP method and I got this Boolean equation 
$$(B + D).(B+C)$$
Is this correct? If not how to approach this problem? What does phi of 12, 13 mean here? Are they don't care values?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It *may* be two separate control inputs apart from the A,B,C,D.

Comment: @PeterSmith How can I approach this problem? Firstly I'm just looking to derive a boolean equation from given values. I can't understand how to solve it with Kmap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boolean expression to NOR-gates](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/172663/boolean-expression-to-nor-gates) .. and many more..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've already seen that question and many other and it doesn't seem to be help me. I would really appreciate if you could help on how to derive Boolean equation from given values? Also what does phi refer here? I'm looking for a way to solve it using K-Map which I'm comfortable with?

Comment: \$\Phi\$ is denoting the combinations which are *don't cares*.

Comment: So is the Boolean equation that I've got correct? or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Draw a truth table for the given equation. Draw the same for your result and compare. Note, that since there are don't cares you may get different *correct* results.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was not given any equation. I think I have to derive an equation from using kmap? isn't it? If I was not given any equation how can I draw a truth table?

Comment: The \$\Pi\$ notation is equivalent to equation - that is what I meant, but it is even easier to translate to a truth table.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I really don't know how to derive truth table for given $$\prod$$ notation?

Comment: How did you reach that answer using kmap ....??? Can you show us ?

Comment: @MituRaj I've done something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViSdX.jpg. Actually Now I'm getting (B + D) * (A + D) as the answer. There was one extra 1 in kmap table should it be considered? Is that what I"m doing wrong here.

Comment: @MituRaj If I'm wrong can you post the solution on how to derive this (even a screenshot is fine). I'm stuck at this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wont be appropriate to post full solution, but will point out your errors.

- Your Kmap is unfortunately flawed. 
  $$f(A,B,C,D) = \prod (0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10) + \Phi(12, 13)$$

Here, maxterms \$(12, 13)\$ are dont cares and you have to fill all other maxterms with **0s** in Kmap and round the biggest groups of zeroes. But you have filled them with 1s as like minterms.

- After rounding process, you will get an SOP expression for \$f'(A,B,C,D)\$. You have to take its complement to get the POS expression for \$f(A,B,C,D)\$ .

Comment: Even though I misplaced 1 in place of zeros I still got the boxes correct isn't it?

Comment: Yea...but the expression is still wrong ..

Comment: Should I also consider that single one in the middle? I'm basically getting (B + D) * (B + C) * (A + B' + C' + D')? Is this correct?

Comment: yep....you got it ;)

Comment: Can I know what they mean by Realize using NOR gates only? Do I have to draw logic diagram using NOR (universal gate) based on the Boolean equation that I've got above? (or) just construct a truth table?

Comment: yea...thats right ...

Comment: you mean drawing logic diagram right?

Comment: logic gate diagram ..